# apache Bval nested collections

Tags: java, bean-validation

Is validation of nested collections built into Apache BVal? If so, how do you use it?

Hibernate Validator seems to have a built in @Valid annotation, but I can't seem to find anything similar in Apache BVal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@Valid` annotation is defined by the Bean Validation specification (JSR 303/349) which is implemented by both, Hibernate Validator (which is the reference implementation) and Apache BVal. So `@Valid` is supposed to work on both implementations.

Comment: Thanks Gunnar.  I just found out exactly that, and was about to indicate that I had found the solution as well.

I was searching online for nested properties and Apache bval and couldn't find anything but did so for Hibernate Validator.  I guess the documentation and usage of Apache bval is much lower than for Hibernate Validator, any idea why that is?